# Copy of a file in pdf document

Tags: coursework

My Lecturer says as follows for a report I have to do:

[image]

I am not sure if this means screenshots of the file content or actual physical copies of the files which you can click on and go into.

The report has to be in PDF format and I am not even sure if PDF supports this feature ? If so how would you do this ?

Comment: Ask your Lecture or their TAs this question, please.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a tool (Latex / Word / ...) to generate the pdf file. You can use this tool to include copies of the required files. For instance, if you use Word, you copy and paste the files into your document, maybe choosing a different font. If you use Latex, you just copy and paste the file contents into a verbatim environment. Then you create the pdf file as usual, and, voilà, you have the files in the appendix.